# How do I get the total Json record count using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, json

I couldn't find anything about getting the total JSON record count using jQuery.

Here is the JSON returned:

`{"Email":"Please enter your Email.","Password":"Please enter a password."}`

Here is my code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/account/signup",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { 
                Email: $("#strEmail").val(),
                Password: $("#strPassword").val()
            },
            success: function(j) {
                    $(".errMsg").hide();
                    alert(j.length); // I couldn't get the total count
                $.each(j, function(n) {
                    $("#err" + n).html(j[n]);
                    $("#err" + n).show();
                })

            },
            error: function(req, status, error) {
                alert(req);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: But the $.each in success handler shows the correct records?

Comment: Yes, everything works well except the total record count.

Comment: Why do you need the record count?

The $.each works as expected, right?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

If you have something like this:

```
var json = [ {a:b, c:d}, {e:f, g:h, ...}, {..}, ... ]
```

then, you can do:

```
alert(json.length)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I tried your code, but i doesn't work for me.

Comment: This shows the JSON string length, not the array count

Comment: Thank you @tiago!  You ultimately gave me my solution and was the following:

`success: function (response) {
    console.log(response.length);
},`

Answer (score 15):

The OP is trying to count the number of properties in a JSON object. This could be done with an incremented temp variable in the iterator, but he seems to want to know the count before the iteration begins. A simple function that meets the need is provided at the bottom of [this page](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=168120).

Here's a cut and paste of the code, which worked for me:

```
function countProperties(obj) {
  var prop;
  var propCount = 0;

  for (prop in obj) {
    propCount++;
  }
  return propCount;
}
```

This should work well for a JSON object. For other objects, which may derive properties from their prototype chain, you would need to add a hasOwnProperty() test.

Answer (score 6):

Why would you want length in this case?

If you do want to check for length, have the server return a JSON array with key-value pairs like this:

```
[
  {key:value},
  {key:value}
]
```

In JSON, [ and ] represents an array (with a length property), { and } represents a object (without a length property). You can iterate through the members of a object, but you will get functions as well, making a length check of the numbers of members useless except for iterating over them.

Answer (score 6):

Try the following:

```
var count=Object.keys(result).length;
```

Does not work IE8 and lower.

Answer (score 4):

Your json isn't an array, it hasn't length property. 
You must change your data return or the way you get your data count.

Comment: Even I changed the Json result (I'm sure it's correct), the length still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is

```
j.d.length
```

The **d** is the key. At least it is in my case, I'm using a .NET webservice.

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "CantTellU.asmx",
            data: "{'userID' : " + parseInt($.query.get('ID')) + " }",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg, status) {
                ApplyTemplate(msg);
                alert(msg.d.length);
            }
        });
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, I called "hasOwnProperty" which has the "length" available but it returned false. Perhaps it was specific to the structure of my JSON however.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you might want to try JSON.parse your return result first then you can get the count by .length