# Get record count Jquery from json return

Tags: jquery

Here is my json return

```
{"data":
{
"4":{"my data is here"}
,"3":{"my data is here"}
,"2":{"my data is here"}
,"1":{"my data is here"}
}
}
```

I have four records, how do I write .length to set var

Here is my jquery each

```
$.each(thedata.data, function()
```

returns all data fine and great I want to do get the amount of records in a var.

this does not work.

```
var theRecordNumber = thedata.data.length;
```

How can I set a variable to the amount of records returned

Comment: PLease see the following top answer from another post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453209/how-do-i-get-the-total-json-record-count-using-jquery

Comment: First, take a minute and clean up your question. What does that last sentence mean?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript object literal length === undefined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690520/javascript-object-literal-length-undefined)

Comment: That's not a valid JSON. -> Ex: `"4":{"my data is here"}` is not valid.. May be it should be either `"4":"my data is here"` or `"4":["my data is here"]`

Comment: @Vega you should post that as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a valid JSON. `"4":{"my data is here"}` is not valid..

It should be either `"4":"my data is here"` or `"4":["my data is here"]`